# How to properly escape SQL when using BindingSource's Filter property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've inherited a C# application that lists data from a database table via a DataGridView. There are also a few text fields used to filter that data. This is done like so:

```
String listFilter = string.Format("City = '{0}'", this.toolStripSearch.Text);
this.customersBindingSource.Filter = listFilter;
```

toolStripSearch is a text field for searching by city name. The problem is that there is no SQL escaping. Adding a quote to the field crashes the app.

What is the proper way of escaping SQL here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the 'correct' way for `BindingSource.Filter` is to simply escape the single quotes using `''` as horrible as that sounds. E.g, something like.

```
String listFilter = string.Format("City = '{0}'", this.toolStripSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''")); 
this.customersBindingSource.Filter = listFilter;
```

The `Filter` property uses the same syntax as `DataColumn` expressions when `BindingSource` is bound to data from a database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx

You can find documentation on the required syntax here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

From that link:

> String values should be enclosed
>   within single quotation marks (and
>   each single quotation character in a
>   string value has to be escaped by
>   prepending it with another single
>   quotation character).

Comment: Actually, I think he will just want to do ... this.toolStripSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''")(There are single quotes in there) .... right? Because he only needs to escape the filter text, not the whole filter statement.

Comment: @Tony - yep, you're correct - my original code was wrong. It's now been corrected.