# Preparing BindingSource filter with user input

Tags: .net, winforms, bindingsource

I'd like to create a `BindingSource.Filter` from a user input, e.g.:

```
bindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[Name] like '%{0}%'", nameFilterTextBox.Text)
```

Obviously a single quotation mark in the user-entered filter string breaks the filter syntax. How can I avoid this? Is there something like prepared statements for this kind of filters?

Simply escaping single quotes just leads to other problems; similar to SQL injection.

Comment: See [How to properly escape SQL when using BindingSource's Filter property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3699724/719186)  Probably not the answer you were hoping for.

Comment: @LarsTech Well, knowing there is no better way, is better than endlessly searching for it... ;) Thanks! Didn't find that question before.